# issue with igztop, show mlrun/nuclio function for k8s pods

Tags: command-line, mlrun, nuclio, igztop

Issue, How can I show addition mlrun parameters such as name of mlrun/nuclio function for k8s pods from `igztop`? It is not a problem to show for pod name also mlrun project name and owner name.

I used igztop version 0.1.3 with this command `igztop -w` and I got the output:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| NAME                                                         | CPU(m) | MEMORY(Mi) | NODE      | STATUS  | MLRun Proj. | MLRun Owner | Req. (Mem) | Lim. (Mem) | Req. (CPU) | Lim. (CPU) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| workflow-controller-5c7cc648f5-k5cf8                         | 2      | 30         | k8s-node2 | Running |             |             | 100Mi      | 12Gi       | 50m        |            |
| authenticator-6d989ddd9b-j4b5c                               | 1      | 9          | k8s-node2 | Running |             |             | 1Mi        |            |            |            |
| v3io-webapi-vdprp                                            | 10     | 1723       | k8s-node2 | Running |             |             | 1Mi        |            |            |            |
|
```

Thanks for experience sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `igztop >= 0.1.4` (parameters are little different than in the version 0.1.3, check `igztop -h`). You can see mlrun name of functions in case of command `igztop -o mlrun`, see the outputs:

```
[jist@iguazio-system (base)] ~ $ ./igztop-0.1.4 -o mlrun
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------+-----------+---------+-------+-----+----------+
| NAME                                                         | CPU   | MEMORY  | NODE      | PROJECT | OWNER | RUN | FUNCTION |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------+-----------+---------+-------+-----+----------+
| v3iod-j7wmd                                                  | 7m    | 5602Mi  | k8s-node2 |         |       |     |          |
| v3iod-4ch67                                                  | 8m    | 5580Mi  | k8s-node1 |         |       |     |          |
| v3iod-nbdlp                                                  | 7m    | 5579Mi  | k8s-node3 |         |       |     |          |
| mlrun-api-chief-6457d6f8dc-6jggx                             | 961m  | 4712Mi  | k8s-node1 |         |       |     |          |
| docker-registry-5f5fddcdf6-47fck                             | 1m    | 2820Mi  | k8s-node2 |         |       |     |          |
| v3io-webapi-vdprp                                            | 11m   | 1723Mi  | k8s-node2 |         |       |     |          |
| v3io-webapi-v4s5c                                            | 11m   | 1718Mi  | k8s-node3 |         |       |     |          |
```